# Azure Kubernetes Error when running "az aks get-credentials --resource-group AKSResourceGroupName --name AKSClusterName" command

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am getting this error(ResourceGroupNotFound) while running this command <az aks get-credentials --resource-group AKSResourceGroupName --name AKSClusterName>

Error message :-

az aks get-credentials --resource-group AKSResourceGroupName --name AKSClusterName
(ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group 'AKSResourceGroupName' could not be found.
Code: **ResourceGroupNotFound**
Message: Resource group 'AKSResourceGroupName' could not be found.

Comment: Replace `AKSResourceGroupName` with the name of your resource group....the same for the cluster name.

Answer (score 3):

First, please check your subscription and select correct subscription:

```
az account list --output table    
az account set --subscription <name or id>
```

then you doing everything correct:

```
az aks get-credentials --name AKSClusterName --resource-group AKSResourceGroupName
```

Answer (score 1):

`az aks get-credentials` command is used to
Get access credentials for a managed Kubernetes cluster.

Example:

```
az aks get-credentials --name MyManagedCluster --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

**name** and **resource-group** are required parameters  where you should provide Name of your managed cluster and Name of your resource group.